# Space between images

Tags: html

**Please help me remove the white space between my images when rendering the below on a browser - FireFox in my case**

```html
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <table style="border:0px;margin:0px;float:left; width:864px">
            <tr>
         <td style="width:809px">
          <table style="margin:0px; border:0px; clear: both; border-collapse: collapse; width:848px; height:120px">
           <tr><td style="margin:0px; border:0px; background:url(images/qualhisttop.jpg); width:560px; height:124px; background-repeat:no-repeat;"></td></tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <table style="border:0px;margin:0px; clear:both; width:864px">
        <tr style="margin:0px;">
            <!----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
            <!--                     B E G I N     N A V I G A T I O N                                           -->
            <!----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
            <td style="border:0px; margin:0px; vertical-align:top; float:left; width:130px; height:532px">
               <img src="images/tp_collagebasedrill.jpg" style="width:130px; height:78px; border:0px;margin:0px;" alt=""/>
                <img src="images/meta_swooshbottom.gif" width="109" height="140" alt="" />
           </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: Step 1: Send the table-based layout back to 2005 where it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

OK so i have provided an example that may help you.`

```
  <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>remove the white space between my images</title>
<style type="text/css">
.wrapper{
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#image-1{
    float: left;
}

#image-1 img{
    width: 600px;
}

#image-2{
    float: left;
}

#image-2 img{
    width: 600px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="image-1"><img src="lostsouls.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div id="image-2"><img src="lostsouls.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OK, I tried this.  The images are next to each other.  How do I get them on top of one another without white space between.  Thanks!

Comment: well you would remove the float left attributes from the image-1 and image-2 id's

Comment: This what I tried and it still shows a space between the images   <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>remove the white space between my images</title>
<style type="text/css">
.containerdiv { float: left; position: relative; } 
.wrapper{
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#image-1{
    
}

#image-1 img{
    width: 600px;
}

#image-2{
    
}

#image-2 img{
    width: 130px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="image-1"><img src="images/qualhisttop.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div id="image-2"><img src="images/tp_collagebasedrill.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: It's weird,  In Visual Studio in "design" it shows no space but when I render to FireFox or IE there is white space between

Answer (score 0):

so if you wanted to stack them then they would be block level elements which are what divs are. Here is how to do that based on the previous example.

```
  <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>remove the white space between my stacked images</title>
<style type="text/css">
.wrapper{
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#image-1{
    border: thin solid #003333;
    height: 200px;  
}

#image-1 img{
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
}

#image-2{
    height: 200px;
}

#image-2 img{
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;

}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="image-1"><img src="lostsouls.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div id="image-2"><img src="lostsouls.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

just make sure that you set the height of the image-1 and image 2 divs to the same size as the image

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  I think I got it!

Answer (score 0):

i provided another code example that should work for you in a previous post. Try that and see if it works. also the reason for the space in between the images is that you must set the height of the image to be the same height as the container or div that the image is inside. So if the image is 400px high then you must set the height of the div to 400px as well. I hope this helps.